# HTML Paths not working when opened outside of VSCode

Tags: html, path

I am learning HTML and i am keeping my secondary websites in `/subwebsites/website.html`

/ is the root folder containing also index.html:

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l8CW.png)

However, opening the subwebsites anywhere outside of the VSCode live server browser makes the subwebsites not be able to find any stylesheet, other .html file or image anymore. It works with the index.html, but as soon as the website is contained in a subfolder it won't work anymore. I am sure it has to do with the way my paths are set but i tried everything I know off:

```
styles/main.css
./styles/main.css
/styles/main.css
```

[picture showing how i added my paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsWTl.png)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case your html file need to go one level up. So for this you can easily use `../`.

So just use this:

`../styles/main.css` ^_^

or

`./../styles/main.css` for your subwebsites.

But better to think to start use some kind of local server. For example, [live-server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) for VSCode.

**Also useful information for you:**

- `/` - root of the current drive
- `./` - current directory
- `../` - parent of the current directory

Comment: ok, so there is no way to kinda give it a "local root" folder? because i assume when you get into subfolders of subfolders of something this gets quite annoying to do. And it obv seems to be somewhat possible since this is alr what VSCode does

Comment: @rafe for this you should use some local server. In this case root will be `/`. You can search for `live-server` for VSCode

Comment: ik about live-server, i have been using that and it works fine there. just not outside of that. And it will need to work in an enviroment where it isnt directly root on the server as i am also submitting this for a school project (and i dont trust my teacher enough to figure this out even with a step by step explanation haha)

Comment: @rafe try to use in sub html files `./../styles/main.css`. If it will help I add it to answer.

Comment: @rafe does it help?

Comment: using ./../styles/main.css does indeed work but it just seems like an inefficient way yk. thats why i have been looking for more but ty. will mark it as answer as is

Answer (score -1):

you can use ~/styles/main.css or ../styles/main.css

../ is previous folder
~/ is root of server

The reason, may be server look for style inside this folder. And can't find it.